# Tag virtual users in k6

Tags: javascript, tags, performance-testing, influxdb, k6

Is it possible in k6 to tag virtual users?

I launch several k6 tests at once, and in my Grafana I want to see different graphs for virtual users joining the test. However, now I can only see the common value for all the tests, as in the InfluxDB there are not any tags which allow to differ virtual users from test to test.

I tried some options with tags, but I was able only to tag the requests which is not the solution.

Comment: What do you want to tag? What values do you want to use for tagging?

Comment: @knittl I want to tag virtual users, all of them per test. I mean, I launch 3 tests with k6 run at once, every test has 100 virtual users. Using Grafana+Influx I can create a graph showing virtual users growing from 1 to 300. My question is how to divide them, and be able to create a graph for each test showing growing VUs from 1 to 100 x3.

Comment: So you don't want to tag virtual users, you want to tag your tests, i.e. set global tags for all VUs of a test script?

Comment: @knittl kind of, right, any solution will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set test-wide tags for all metrics [via options](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/k6-options/reference/#tags):

```
export const options = {
    tags: {
        mytag: 'myvalue',
    },
};
```

You may also specify them via the command line as `--tag mytag=myvalue`.